Can Hindu Gods reincarnate
Can Gods reincarnate in a body for helping their devotees ?
I am not talking about mythological characters to help humanity I am talking about daily life, thus means living a full life as a reincarnation just to stay with a devotee.
if yes please provide scriptures passages .

God resides in all beings (living and non-living). When God helps you, you never really realise that he helped you. For example in Gita Chapter 1 Arjuna is worried about his situation but he was unaware that Lord Krishna had already made him victorious. Arjuna did not realise it since we as humans are bound by time. We can't really understand God's mysterious ways. So even if he were to reincarnate for us, we would not realise it. Can he? Definitely, there's nothing he can't do. Would we realise it? Probably not in Kaliyuga.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
